# Purchase a Google Drive plan for someone else?

Tags: google-drive, online-storage

My mom and sister are starting to use Google drive to upload their photos and other files, they are soon to be running out of space. On my personal account I have a 100GB plan purchased ($2/m) and I'd like to buy the same plan for their accounts. I don't want to add my CC info in their accounts.

Is it possible to pay or buy Google Drive space on behalf of someone else?

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not currently possible to purchase storage plans for someone else using a personal account, though it is possible to do so if the account is using Google Apps for Work.

Comment: Any updates on that since 2014?